# fetchrow_hashref or fetchhash?

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

i am wondering if someone can help me with a frustrating problem with an old perl code. My actual task is to migrate an old perl script from Version 5.10.1 to 5.18.2.

So i've done already the simple problems with the script like wrong calls, bad format, ect.

But im stuck on a function called fetchhash with seem to be like fetchrow_hashref;

Im intended to catch a list of IPs, Nameserver IDs and Names. My Problem is, that the function fetchrow_hashref doesn't do the same thing like fetchhash in the old code.

see folllowing new code:

```
        #fetch_network();
        $res2=$dbh->prepare("select nsip,nsid,nsname from nameservers");
        $res2->execute();

        while (%ns2=$res2->fetchrow_hashref;{
            $nsips{$ns2{nsid}}=$ns2{nsip};
            $nsnames{$ns2{nsid}}=$ns2{nsname};
        }
```

The table looks like:

```
+-----------------+------+------------------------------+
| nsip            | nsid | nsname                       |
+-----------------+------+------------------------------+
| 101.101.111.10  |    1 | ns1.yournameserver.net       |
```

Here is a part of the old code:

```
$res2=$dbh->query("select nsip,nsid,nsname from nameservers");
while (%ns2=$res2->fetchhash)
{
$nsips{$ns2{nsid}}=$ns2{nsip};
$nsnames{$ns2{nsid}}=$ns2{nsname};
}
```

So i tried with fetchrow_hashref but it did'nt work for me:

```
main::(nsconfgen.pl:170):               while (%ns2=$res2->fetchrow_hashref){
DB<193> n
Reference found where even-sized list expected at nsconfgen.pl line 170.
at nsconfgen.pl line 170.
main::(nsconfgen.pl:171):                     $nsips{$ns2{nsid}}=$ns2{nsip};
DB<193> p $ns2{nsid}

( i've get no value from the hash )
```

Of course i've crawled through Google and i tried a lot of examples but nothing helps realy...

So i hope i can get here some help.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm guessing that code uses the ancient [Mysql.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-3.0008/lib/Mysql.pm) module, which was obsolete even in 2006. If so, you'll need to make a lot more changes than just `fetchhash` -> `fetchrow_hashref`. Does your script have `use Mysql;` somewhere?

Comment: ouch, i guess it is very old :D Yes, there is a use Mysql; in the beginning of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `DBI` implementors, the return value of `fetchrow_hashref` is a reference to a hash, not a hash. A few changes to your code will get it right:

```
    while ($ns2=$res2->fetchrow_hashref) {
        $nsips{$ns2->{nsid}}=$ns2->{nsip};
        $nsnames{$ns2->{nsid}}=$ns2->{nsname};
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, it sounds plausible. But on %ns2=$res2->fetchrow_hashref --- i get the error ->> Reference found where even-sized list expected at nsconfgen.pl <<--- then on $nsips{$ns2->{nsid}}=$ns2->{nsip}; i've get the error Use of uninitialized value in hash element at nsconfgen.pl line 172. ---- i

Comment: @strader: You haven't copied the first line of mob's code correctly

Comment: oh! thank you very much! I've overlooked the line :D Now it works. A thousand thanks.